# python nesting dictionary: OrderedDict from collections

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

how to nest a OrderedDict?

i tried:

```
table=collections.OrderedDict()
table['E']['a']='abc'
```

but this shows error.

i tried also:

```
table=collections.OrderedDict(OrderedDict())
table['E']['a']='abc'
```

this also shows error.

i tried:

```
table=collections.OrderedDict()
table['E']=collections.OrderedDict()
table['E']['a']='abc'
```

this works fine.

in my coding i had to use like this:

```
table=collections.OrderedDict()
for lhs in left:
    table[lhs]=collections.OrderedDict()
    for val in terminal:
        table[lhs][val]=0
```

which works fine. but is there any other method. as i read python manages its data structure automatically.

is there anyway to declare a dictionary along with how much nesting it'll be and what will be the data-structures of its nests in one line.

using an extra loop just to declare a dictionary feels like i'm missing something in python.

Comment: if any admin or such type of user reading this, i want to ask the concept of upvote and downvote. it's based on research efforts or anything other? sometimes it feels like someone is taking revenge or this site is only for pros in a language. what type of research effort this question is not showing? if it's not useful, then i'd not be asking. if i could find it with googling, i'd bot be asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to do it in one line, then this would work

```
table = collections.OrderedDict([(lhs, collections.OrderedDict(zip(terminal, [0] * len(terminal)))) for lhs in left])
```

You would be best off (especially if terminal has a lot of members) doing

```
zipped = zip(terminal, [0] * len(terminal))
table = collections.OrderedDict([(lhs, collections.OrderedDict(zipped)) for lhs in left])
```

Comment: that `0` initialization will be part of my rest coding. i just needed the nesting part. thanks. i can remove the zip part. :D

Comment: What is `terminal` and `lhs` here?

Answer (score 12):

You can define your own custom subclass of `OrderedDict`, handle the `__missing__` method to support infinite nesting.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        val = self[key] = MyDict()
        return val
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d['b']['c']['e'] = 100
>>> d['a']['c']['e'] = 100
>>> d.keys()
['b', 'a']
>>> d['a']['d']['e'] = 100
>>> d['a'].keys()
['c', 'd']
```

Comment: At the time I asked the question, I didn't know class concepts that well. Now when I look back at it, your answer is a much better and sophisticated one. As I say, The Pythonic way to do it. Thanks for such an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderedDefaultDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = default_factory
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        val = self[key] = self.default_factory()
        return val
```

It's simple enough to subclass `OrderedDict` with `defaultdict`-like behavior. You can then use an `OrderedDefaultDict` as follows:

```
table = OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict)
table['a']['b'] = 3
```

Comment: And if he wants infinite nesting, he would have to define something like ``def factory(): return OrderedDefaultDict(factory)`` and pass it to the root constructor.

Comment: I updated the answer with `val = self[key] = self.__class__(self.default_factory)`. It is pending peer review. I tested and it works for me.

Comment: @Rafe: Edit rejected, because the intent was to create a class combining general OrderedDict and defaultdict behavior. Your edit reduces the class's generality by hardcoding a specific behavior for missing keys; in particular, the `default_factory` is no longer actually used for anything under your edit.

Comment: @user2357112: I think this answer's pattern should be considered broken without my edit. It isn't nesting itself as requested. It is flat. Just try going one more level deep and it fails. default_factory is still passed to the base class via super().

Comment: @Rafe: This answer is not intended to nest infinitely by default. It is supposed to be a combination of OrderedDict and defaultdict, applying a user-provided default factory. It can be configured to nest infinitely with an appropriate default factory (`def tree(): return OrderedDefaultDict(tree)`), but it can also be configured to nest to a fixed, finite level, or to do other things. There is already another answer that provides hardcoded infinite nesting.