# How to make a dictionary nested in a nested dictionary an OrderedDict (Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and I require the nested dictionaries within the dictionary to be ordered.

```
meta = {'task': {'id': 'text',
        'name': 'text',
        'size': '',
        'mode': 'interpolation',
        'overlap': '5',
        'bugtracker': '', 
        'created': '',
        'updated': '',
        'start_frame': '',
        'stop_frame': '',
        'frame_filter': '',
        'labels': {'label': {'name': 'text',
            'color': 'text',
            'attributes': {'attributes': {'name': 'text',
                         'mutable': 'False',
                         'input_type': 'text',
                         'default_value': '',
                         'values': '',}}}}}}
meta = collections.OrderedDict(meta)
```

I tried using a list as shown below using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412746/keep-input-order-in-nested-dictionaries):

```
meta = {'task': [('id', 'text'),
        ('name', 'text'),
        ('size',''),
        ('mode', 'interpolation'),
        ('overlap', '5'),
        ('bugtracker', ''), 
        ('created', ''),
        ('updated', ''),
        ('start_frame', ''),
        ('stop_frame', ''),
        ('frame_filter', '')]}
```

But this does not work for dictionaries nested within a nested dictionary. How can I convert the entire dictionary to be an OrderedDict, even the innermost nested dictionaries?

P.S. I have a feeling the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809482/python-nesting-dictionary-ordereddict-from-collections) is what I need but I cannot seem to figure out what the variables `terminal` and `lhs` are here. If anyone can help with this, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: Try: `meta = json.loads(json.dumps(meta), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)`

Comment: Are you sure you need an `OrderedDict`? `OrderedDict` takes key order into account for equality testing; `dict` does not. Otherwise, there's no difference between the two since Python 3.7.

Comment: @chepner I need an OrderedDict as I convert this to XML and the order should be the same as the keys in the dictionary

Comment: You can do that with a regular `dict` as of Python 3.7; the insertion order of a key is remembered for iteration.

Comment: E.g., `{a: 1, b: 2}.keys() == [a, b]` is now guaranteed, no matter what values `a` and `b` have. It's no longer dependent on the hash values used to insert `a` and `b` into the `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

This calls for recursion:

```
def convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return OrderedDict((k, convert(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
    # possibly, if your data contains lists
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [*map(convert, obj)]
    return obj

meta = convert(meta)
```